# Error when using or operator in a function argument type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I have this interface:

```
interface SimpleAddCase {
  addedAppointment: AddedAppointment;
  addCb: AddCallback;
}

interface ContinuousAddCase extends SimpleAddCase {
  removedAppointment: AddedAppointment;
  removeCb: RemoveCallback;
}

type AddedAppointmentArgs = SimpleAddCase | ContinuousAddCase;

type AddAppointment = (args: AddedAppointmentArgs) => void;
```

but when I pass an instance like this:

```
addAppointmentCallbackContinuousCase = ({
    addedAppointment: { day, number, time, id },
    addCb,
    removedAppointment: params,
    removeCb
  }: ContinuousAddCase): void => {
...}
```

I use addAppointmentCallbackContinuousCase as a prop for a react component.

```
<AppointmentPicker
          addAppointmentCallback={this.addAppointmentCallbackContinuousCase}
        />
```

And assign this function to that prop, give me this error:

```
Type '({ addedAppointment: { day, number, time, id }, addCb, removedAppointment: params, removeCb }: ContinuousAddCase) => void' is not assignable to type 'AddAppointment'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'args' are incompatible.
    Type 'AddedAppointmentArgs' is not assignable to type 'ContinuousAddCase'.
      Type 'SimpleAddCase' is missing the following properties from type 'ContinuousAddCase': removedAppointment, removeCbts(2322)
```

Does someone know how could it be solved?

Comment: I think what you've done has created cyclic dependency and confused the compiler. Instead can you create a interface that contains common props and then create another interfaces that extends the common interface. In that case your props will easily be interpreted by ts compiler

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could solve it by using this form:

```js
    interface SimpleAddCaseInterface {
      addedAppointment: AddedAppointmentInterface;
      addCb: AddCallbackType;
    }
    
    interface ContinuousAddCaseInterface extends SimpleAddCaseInterface {
      removedAppointment: AddedAppointmentInterface;
      removeCb: RemoveCallbackType;
    }
    
    type AddAppointmentType = (
      args: ContinuousAddCaseInterface | SimpleAddCaseInterface
    ) => void;
```

and I could instance it by using:

```js
interface SimpleAddCaseInterface {
  addedAppointment: AddedAppointmentInterface;
  addCb: AddCallbackType;
}

interface ContinuousAddCaseInterface extends SimpleAddCaseInterface {
  removedAppointment?: AddedAppointmentInterface;
  removeCb?: RemoveCallbackType;
}

//Into a class

addAppointmentCallbackContinuousCase = ({
    addedAppointment: { day, number, time, id },
    addCb,
    removedAppointment: params,
    removeCb
  }: ContinuousAddCaseInterface): void => {...}


<AppointmentPicker
          addAppointmentCallback={this.addAppointmentCallbackContinuousCase}
        />
```